# Redirecting "nonexistent" folders/subfolders/files to domain root

Tags: .htaccess

I transfered website to a new host. Before the transfer there were some folders which are not needed anymore. Since they are still getting traffic, I would like to 301 them and all the "content" inside them to domain's root.

**I don't want to redirect ALL of 404, only when user is accessing specific url slug and its additions (folders are deleted).**

For example:

domain.com/old-folder/* -> domain.com

domain.com/older-folder/* -> domain.com

I was able to redirect ALL 404 to index and only roots of "old-folder" and "older-folder" to root - but not the content within the folders, which is my ultimate goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: And should the redirections point directly to the "root" or should the relative path inside those old folders be kept?

Comment: @arkascha Those folders are not on the server anymore. Which means that all the visitors trying to access "/old-folder" and "/older-folder", including paths of previous subfolders and files withing them -> should redirect to domain root. So if the visitor goes to domain.com/old-folder/sub-folder/index.html -> domain.com .... If the visitor goes to domain.com/old-folder -> domain.com

Comment: Sure, I just ask because the physical absence of those folders does not automatically mean that the resources and thus paths do not make sense any more. Todays web sites are _not_ a mapping of URLs to a physical file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use conditions testing if the requests target one of those folders you removed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old-folder [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/older-folder
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301]
```